# Deploy SPA for Prod environment

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

I am new to Web Development. Tried to build a production build with the command `npm run build`. I tried to run index.html after the build is completed, all I get was a 404 page.

However, when I tried to run it with `http-server`, I'm able to visit my website and all the pages in it. I'm unsure what this means?

- With what I have, am I ready to publish all files in `build` to my PROD server?
- If not, what is missing?

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
```

Comment: Which Http server are you using on the PROD server?

Comment: Not using any http server. Do I need one? Planning to host on AWS S3 since its a SPA

Comment: build folder has only static content.

Comment: Have you actually tried to upload it? Sometimes what you are saying happened to me but works perfect when I upload it to s3.

Comment: @CarlosSaizOrteu Yea, it actually work by just uploading the content to S3. Still I didn't understand the concept behind why it won't run after `npm run build`. Maybe the code has compiled and no longer runs on localhost? A http-server is needed I suppose.